# How can put margin between divs that have bootstrap classes?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap in a project and I want to put margin between divs and this is my code :

```
<div className="container">
   <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 box">a</div>
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 box mr-1 ml-1">b</div>
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 box">c</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is it doesn't push other divs and break up the whole row , basically it doesn't apply margin properly .

How can put margin between these divs properly ?

Comment: @Manjuboyz It doesn't apply margin correctly between divs

Comment: @Manjuboyz yes would you please try in your own way and show me the code If it works ?

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the margin problem by adding another div inside all divs like this :

```
<div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                        <div className="box ml-1 mr-1">a</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                        <div className="box ml-1 mr-1">b</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                        <div className="box ml-1 mr-1">c</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And now all three divs have margins between .